# C++: how to use std::less<int> with boost::bind and boost::lambda?

Tags: c++, stl, boost, boost-bind, boost-lambda

I am trying to lean boost::bind, boost::lambda libraries and how they can be used with STL algorithms. Suppose I have vector of int-string pairs which is sorted by int key. Then a place to insert a new pair while keeping the vector sorted can be found as follows:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, string> > entries;
...
int k = ...;

// Let's ignore std::lower_bound return value for now
std::lower_bound (entries.begin(), entries.end(), k, 
                  boost::bind (&std::pair<int, string>::first, _1) < k)
```

Now I would like to replace `operator<` with a function object (of type `std::less<int>` in this example):

```
std::less<int> comparator;
```

How do I change the code above so it works? I cannot just do

```
std::lower_bound (entries.begin(), entries.end(), k, 
                  comparator (boost::bind (&std::pair<int, string>::first, _1), k))
```

because `std::less<int>::operator()` does not accept whatever is the return type of `boost::bind`. What am I missing here? TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you're missing is another `bind` (and the template parameters on `pair`):

```
std::lower_bound(entries.begin(), entries.end(), k, 
                 boost::bind(comparator,
                             boost::bind(&std::pair<int, string>::first, _1),
                             k))
```

You don't have to do that on the less-than operator in your original code because Boost.Bind provides overloads for that operator that know how to handle the return type of `boost::bind`.

Comment: So the outer boost::bind does the magic of making comparator.operator() accept whatever the inner boost::bind produces. Thanks! (BTW the missing pair template parameters is just an editing error of mine)

Comment: I was tempted to do this so many times. But when you step back you realize that your code is very hard to read. And now that bind is a part of C++ standard you should note that only boost implementation overloads relational and logical operators.